# Java - Reset or Specialize Security Manager

Tags: java, security, plugins, external

I am trying to build a Plugin System in java without resorting to special libraries.

As of now, I am able to load and process my plugins. However, I need to define a special Security Manager which disables any access to file deletion and others.

This Security Manager should only keep plugins in place, because the core of my system has to perform some actions plugins can't. As a result, I cannot set the Security Manager using the System class, or it will affect my system's core as well.

I've tried to "reset" the default Security Manager after loading the plugins, but I was unable to do that. Even if I was able, the plugins would end up executing the system's current Security Manager, not their own.

I would like to know if there is a way to encapsulate classes to specific Security Managers.

On top of my head, I was thinking on looking the stack trace and, if a plugin class is found as a caller, forbid the actions they should not perform, but I fear this will prove to be a little ineffective performance-wise.

<del>As soon as I am able, I will post the code to my Security Manager in order to help with ideas.</del>

Here is the code for my Security Manager:

```
package org.zeh.filemanager.core.controllers.util;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;

/**
 * @author José Ricardo Carvalho Prado de Almeida
*/
public class PluginSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
    @Override
    public void checkRead(FileDescriptor filedescriptor) {
        super.checkRead(filedescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(String filename) {
        super.checkRead(filename);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(String filename,
                          Object executionContext) {
        //
        super.checkRead(filename,
                        executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkWrite(FileDescriptor filedescriptor) {
        throw new SecurityException("Plugin is trying to write files.");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkWrite(String filename) {
        throw new SecurityException("Plugin is trying to write files.");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkDelete(String file) {
        super.checkDelete(file);
        throw new SecurityException("Plugin is trying to delete files.");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkExec(String cmd) {
        super.checkExec(cmd);
        throw new SecurityException("Plugin is trying to create subprocesses.");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        super.checkExit(status);
        throw new SecurityException("Plugin is trying to finalize the JVM.");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkCreateClassLoader() {
        super.checkCreateClassLoader();
        throw new SecurityException("Plugin is trying to create ClassLoaders.");
    }
}
```

I have found a question ([How to implement Java plugin security safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281695/how-to-implement-java-plugin-security-safely?rq=1)), that is very similar to mine but the answers do not really fit in my context, where external libraries are not desired.

I forgot to mention that I do have a custom Class Loader that is working perfectly as of now.

I've designed the program so each kind of plugin would have a special Class Loader and such loader would have it's own Security Manager, to restrict different plugins based on functionality.

The only reason this design does not work is because of those Security Managers. If I ignore the use of Security Managers, the system does everything it is supposed to, although it is not secure.

Does anyone have a probable solution for this problem?
Thank you.